# Prove this Ramanujan series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation, ramanujan-summation

> Prove how this series: $\frac{1}{1^3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^3}\cdot\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3}\cdot\frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{4^3}\cdot\frac{1}{2^4} +...= \frac{1}{6}(\log 2)^3+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}(\log 2) + (\frac{1}{1^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{5^3}+..)$

I don't know how to begin but I know that the left-hand side is of the form $$\sum\frac{1}{n^3}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: I don't think this equation is correct. The LHS is $0.537\dots$ but the RHS is $1.67\dots$. If you meant $\boxed{-}\frac{\pi^2}{12}(\log{(2)})$ then I believe the equation is correct.

Comment: @PeterForeman How can you exactly calculate it. It is an infinite series. The number I have entered on LHS is not equal to RHS.

Comment: I just used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+inf+of+1%2F%28n%5E3+2%5En%29) (an online computer algebra system). It even gives the desired simplification.

Comment: But clearly the current 'equality' is incorrect as the LHS is less than the geometric series $1/2+1/2^2+\dots=1$ but the RHS is greater than $1$ as all the terms are positive and one of the terms is exactly $1$.

Comment: To use only algebra precalculus is mandatory?

Comment: Using Antonio's hint, you can enter `PolyLog[3,1/2]` into Wolfram Alpha and get the correct right hand side (not the same as yours, as Peter Foreman points out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $0 < x < 1$ we have

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k = \frac{x}{1-x}
$$

now calling $S_0 = \frac{x}{1-x}$ we have the relationships

$$
x S_3' = S_2\\
x S_2' = S_1\\
x S_1' = S_0
$$

after integration with null constants we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
S_1 & = & -\log (1-x) \\
S_2 & = &  -\log (1-x) \log (x)-\text{Li}_2(1-x) \\
S_3 & = &  -\log (1-x) \log ^2(x)-\text{Li}_2(1-x) \log (x)-\text{Li}_2(x) \log (x)+\text{Li}_3(x) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

making now $x = \frac 12$

$$
\cases{
 S_1(\frac 12)=\log (2) \\
 S_2(\frac 12)= \frac{1}{12} \left(\pi ^2-6 \log ^2(2)\right) \\
 S_3(\frac 12)=\frac{1}{24} \left(4 \log ^3(2)-2\pi ^2\log (2)+21 \zeta (3)\right) \\
}
$$

Answer (score 4):

This is by no means a complete answer but really a long comment. We could also ask if for a fixed number $k$ is it true that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3k^n}=\text{Li}_{3}\left( \frac{1}{k}\right);
$$
where $\text{Li}_{3}()$ is the [trilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html). Really we are computing $\text{Li}_{3}(\frac{1}{2}).$

We have the following functional equation from Euler

$$
\text{Li}_{3}\left(\frac{-z}{1-z}\right)+\text{Li}_{3}(z)+\text{Li}_{3}(1-z)\\
=\zeta(3)+\zeta(2)\log(1-z)-\frac{1}{2}\log(z)\log^2(1-z)+\frac{1}{3}\log^3(1-z)\\
$$

Comment: just to say the functional relation for $Li_3$ follows from that its 2nd derivative is almost $\log(1-z)= -\log(1/(1-z))$